# About the finiteness of Sha(A/K)

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

As this question is pretty vague due to my huge lack of knowledge of the subject, it may not be suitable for MathOverflow, and so I prefer to ask it here.

If I well understood what I read on Wikipedia, the Tate-Shafarevich group of an abelian variety $A$ defined over a number field $K$, denoted $Sha(A/K)$ (I don't know how to type this cyrillic letter in LaTeX) is conjectured to be finite. The article of Wikipedia says that this group consists of the elements of the so-called Weil-Chatelet group of $A$ that become trivial in all completions (real, complex and $p$-adic) of $K$. This made me think of a Galois group as an automorphism group, namely of a field $L'$, whose elements act trivially on the field $L$ whose $L'$ is a Galois extension. In some sense, $Sha(A/K)$ should correspond to some kind of Galois group $Gal(L'/L)$ where both $A$ and the adele ring of $K$ are used to define $L$.

So is there a somewhat natural map $f_{A}:K'\mapsto F_{A,\mathbb{A}_{K'}}$ where $K'$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, $F_{A,\mathbb{A}_{K'}}$ is a number field, and $\mathbb{A}_{K'}$ the adele ring of $K'$, such that $Sha(A/K)\cong Gal(f_{A}(\bar{K})/f_{A}(K))$?

I guess some notion of automorphism of abelian variety for $A$ (which one?) should be used to define $f_{A}$.
Once again I apologize for the vagueness of the question, but I'd be really glad to get any insight. Thanks in advance.